# Access POST fails but GET success via Angular to Springboot, Postman works for both GET & POST

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, postman, okta

I am using sample angular application to test Okta integration with a springboot app.
Front-end sample: https://github.com/okta-samples/okta-angular-sample

I have a springboot microservice with a controller and enabled spring security. I am able to reach endpoint using postman without any issue, however when the request is made via angular I get
**401 Unauthorized** and following are the server log:

```
2024-01-07 19:19:18.499 DEBUG 10476 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.4g.account.controller.AccountController#getOrders()
2024-01-07 19:19:18.511 DEBUG 10476 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-01-07 19:19:18.520 DEBUG 10476 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /account/orders] with attributes [authenticated]
2024-01-07 19:19:18.524 DEBUG 10476 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2024-01-07 19:19:18.524 DEBUG 10476 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IDToken, OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import { OKTA_AUTH } from '@okta/okta-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  orders!: { name: string; value: unknown }[];

  constructor(@Inject(OKTA_AUTH) public oktaAuth: OktaAuth,private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getOrders();
  }
  async getOrders() {
    const accessToken: AccessToken = await this.oktaAuth.tokenManager.get('accessToken') as AccessToken;
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/account/orders';
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken.accessToken}`
    };
    return this.http.post(apiUrl, { headers }).subscribe(data => {
      this.orders = Object.entries(data).map(entry => ({ name: entry[0], value: entry[1] }));
  })
}
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer()
                .authenticationManagerResolver(new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver("https://xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default"));
        http.cors();
    }

}
```

**AccountController.java**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextAccessor securityContextAccessor;
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;
    @PostMapping(value = "/orders")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getOrders() {
        try{
            return new ResponseEntity<>(orderService.getOrders(securityContextAccessor.getJwtToken()), HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(AccountException ae){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

When I change controller from POST to GET the issue is resolved, wondering why it fails for POST request?

Comment: You need to send the access token, not the ID token.

Comment: I am sending idToken only please check my angular code, ```const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken.idToken}`
    };```
The same token that send via angular works when i send via postman

Comment: An ID token only contains a user's information. It cannot be used to access an API. That's not how OAuth works.

Comment: @MattRaible you are correct on idtoken, I have updated the code and question with accesstoken however the issue still persists!

Comment: One thing you might try is adding `withCredentials: true` to your request. `this.http.post(apiUrl, { headers }, withCredentials: true)`

Comment: Same issue, with or without credentials, I am start suspecting non secure protocol used for post and/or calling via  localhost. I have tried axios api too thinking the http client can not able to send all required headers but no luck

Comment: I've successfully integrated Angular and Spring Boot with Okta in the past. I used an `HttpInterceptor` to add the access token. This tutorial is a bit old, but maybe it'll help. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/06/crud-angular-9-spring-boot-2

Comment: @MattRaible Good point, Interceptors can help streamline http requests and may fix this issue, i have used basic call with latest angular version. Possibly all new browsers contributing additional security when using POST here in my case, I'll implement this Interceptor and see how that helps,  thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [current recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), **your Angular app should not be configured as an OAuth2 "public" client** (get tokens from the authorization server). Instead, you should be using the BFF pattern with an OAuth2 "confidential" client running on your servers and have requests authorized with sessions and CSRF protection (misconfiguration of which is a possible cause for your current problem) between Angular and the BFF. I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2) and it works with any OIDC provider (including Okta).

Note that the post I linked 1st was written by Spring Security team mid 2021 and that tutorials should have been fixed since then, but...

Also, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is from older versions of Spring Security and only very deprecated version do not support the new way of defining web security (exposing `SecurityFilterChain` beans). You should switch to that.